# Put method (with Axios on front-end Vue) changing wrong id

Tags: vue.js, axios

I created a web application, and i'm trying to change data with the PUT method, but it only changes the data from the first id, ignoring the url id.
I'm just having problem with the PUT method in the front-end, everything on the back and all other methods in the front are working fine.

Back-end (with node, express and mongodb):

```
app.put('/registros/:id', (req, res) => {
  Registro.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (register) {
res.send(register);
  });
});
```

Front-end ( with Vue and axios):

```
   <template> 
     <form>
       <br />Data:
       <input v-model="date" />
       Descrição:
       <input v-model="description" />
       Tipo:
       <input v-model="type" />
       Valor:
       <input v-model="value" />
    </form>

      <table style="width:100%">
      <tr v-for="registro in registros">
      <button @click="editData(registro._id)">Edit</button>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </template>



  <script>

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        registros: [],
        date: null,
        description: "",
        type: "",
        value: null
       };
     },
    methods: {
      editData(id) {
        let self = this;
          axios
           .put(`http://localhost:3000/registros/${id}`, {
              date: self.date,
              description: self.description,
              type: self.type,
              value: self.value
            })
           .then(function(answ) {});
    </script>
```

Comment: You must specify your params to the findOneAndUpdate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `findOneAndUpdate` should be a filter, not just an id.

Something like:

```
Registro.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, ...
```

The way you have it currently will match all documents and just update the first one.